# O que são arquivos TTML?

Tags: linguagem-de-marcação

Vi que existem um tipo de arquivo com extensão semelhante ao HTML, o TTML, mas ainda não entendi eles.

- O que são os arquivos TTML, e onde utilizo eles?
- Quais as principais diferença entre HTML e TTML? Vi um pequeno trecho na [Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timed_text) da sintaxe dele, muito semelhante ao HTML:

  ```
  <tt xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml">
    <body>
      <div begin="22s" dur="5s">
        <p>I'll teach thee Bugology, Ignatzes</p>
      </div>
      <div begin="40s" dur="3s">
        <p>Something tells me</p>
      </div>
      <div begin="58s" dur="61s">
        <p>Look, Ignatz, a sleeping bee</p>
      </div>
    </body>
  </tt>
  ```
- Esses arquivos podem ser abertos no navegador? É possível adicionar CSS e JS a esses arquivos?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj152136(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É um formato de marcação para textos que precisam de informação do tempo que eles devem ser usados. Sabe as legendas o que povo pega para assistir suas séries favoritas assim que lançam nos países de origem ou assistir seus filmes piratas? Normalmente elas usam o formato `srt`, então tem o tempo  que devem ser mostrado o texto em seguida. O TTML é ligeiramente diferente mas serve ao mesmo propósito e é [padronizado pela W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/ttaf1-dfxp/#media-types-registration).

HTML é uma linguagem para montar páginas web, TTML é para legendas diversas, em geral em produtos de audiovisual. Aos poucos os software terão suporte a ele, você pode fazer um software com suporte a este formato, seja para gerá-lo ou para interpretá-lo.